# Reading sqlite file from dynamic framework

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

I currently use Magic record and a dynamic framework for my database stuff. However, I've been stuck on the same issue for the past 2 days. I can't get my main app which has the embedded framework to create any sort of entity. The context gets created but when I try to do a fetch request, I get entity not found. I tried using a shared container to share the mom file, tried the the nsbundle with the self class, tried hardcoding the bundle id and getting the url for the resource, still no luck. The mom file is definitely copied in the framework because I included it in the copy source file. Any one had any luck getting that to work?

Tried the following:(I think we need the sqlite file)

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"bundleid"] URLForResource:@"model" withExtension:@"momd"];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL:storeURL]
```

Comment: Need more detail.  Don't you just pass the name of the sql file from the app to the framework?

Comment: Basically i can only get it to work when i copy the model to the main app, else it can't open.

Comment: I don't see why that's the case.  The dynamic library is in the same address space as the app and shares sandbox rights etc.

Comment: Yeah I am using a workspace with 2 projects. One is the main app, the 2nd one is the dynamic library with the models etc..

Comment: Are you loading the database from a bundle?  If so which bundle?

Comment: Hello loading it from he framework bundle

Comment: Aren't you confusing the model (.momd) with the store (.sqlite) - the parameter for `setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL` should be a store file, not a model file?

Comment: I tried appending the sqlite file behind.

Comment: Can you show the code that works for a static lib but not for the dynamic framework?  Thanks.

Comment: I use pod for the static lib. I use a shared container to share the model.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your code,

```
// this is data model, not Persistent Store URL
NSURL *storeURL = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"bundleid"] URLForResource:@"model" withExtension:@"momd"];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL:storeURL]; // expect persistent store url
```

Using MagicalRecord, initialization is really simple,

```
// which will collect and merge all data models in the main bundle 
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"my.sqlite"]
```

In MagicalRecordInternal.m, you will find some code of much inspiration, as follows,

```
// *modelClass* can be any class in your dynamic framework
+ (void) setDefaultModelFromClass:(Class)modelClass;
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:modelClass]; 
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:bundle]];
    [NSManagedObjectModel MR_setDefaultManagedObjectModel:model];
}
```

**More details**,

If you create a new *Swift* project named "tmp" with coreData, you will see something like this in AppDelegate.swift.

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("tmp", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

There is no file named `tmp.momd`; and what created by Xcode is `tmp.xcdatamodeld`. An appropriate method is `NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(_:)`, which will search all suitable compiled data model named xx.momd

Comment: I basically can't get it to work reading from a dynamic framework else it is fine.

Comment: What does it mean when you say "else it is fine"? @user281300